# Can someone explain to me in great detail how I can create a custom initializer for UIView properly?

Tags: swift, uiview, initialization, option-type

How come its so hard just to create a custom subclass for UIView? All I want to do is be able to pass a string to the view and set the header of the view to some text but when i try to compile the code I get the error `self.inputField is not initialized at super.init call`.

```
class TextInputView: UIView {
    public var inputField:UITextField

//MARK: Lifecycle

    convenience init(withHeader header:String) {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
        self.inputField = UITextField.init(forAutoLayout: ())

        let headerLbl = UILabel.init(forAutoLayout: ())
        headerLbl.textColor = UIColor.red
        headerLbl.text = header

        headerLbl.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .top, of: self)
        headerLbl.autoPinEdge(.leading, to: .leading, of: self)


        self.inputField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: headerLbl)
        self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.leading, to: .leading, of: self)
        self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.right, to: .right, of: self)
        self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.bottom, to: .bottom, of: self, withOffset: -5)

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

In order to fix this I either have to set inputField! or inputField? can someone explain why? Why does optional chaining need to be involved just to set a custom initializer?

Comment: Think about what happens (or actually, what doesn't happen) if you do: `let myView = TextInputView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))`.

Comment: Dude its not about the size of the frame or anything. ITs about the code not compiling....I just want to know whats the proper way to set a custom initializer. Why is it making me set the instance variables to either optional or the forced unwrapped ! before it allows me to compile

Comment: @rmaddy Why dod I need to set the frame if im using auto layout?

Comment: You completely missed my point. The specifics of the frame are irrelevant. I'm simply pointing out why the compiler is complaining. Look at the code path if that particular initializer of your custom view class is called. Then read the [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) chapter of the Swift book.

Comment: You have to initialize properties of `TextInputView` _before_ you call `super.init`. As the link that rmaddy shared with you says, "A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a superclass initializer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not reasonable to ask stack overflow to “explain in great detail” something that is already explained in great detail in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203).

We can, however, help you understand what is wrong with the initializers you have written. Let's go through them.

Here's your first initializer:

> ```
> convenience init(withHeader header:String) {
>     self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
>     self.inputField = UITextField.init(forAutoLayout: ())
>
>     let headerLbl = UILabel.init(forAutoLayout: ())
>     headerLbl.textColor = UIColor.red
>     headerLbl.text = header
>
>     headerLbl.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .top, of: self)
>     headerLbl.autoPinEdge(.leading, to: .leading, of: self)
>
>
>     self.inputField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
>     self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: headerLbl)
>     self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.leading, to: .leading, of: self)
>     self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.right, to: .right, of: self)
>     self.inputField.autoPinEdge(.bottom, to: .bottom, of: self, withOffset: -5)
>
> }
> ```

Why is this a convenience initializer? It appears that the job of `TextInputView` is to show a header and a text field, and this is the only initializer that does so. Make this your designated initializer by removing `convenience` and initializing the properties before calling `super.init`. Also, it doesn't appear to add the label and the text field as subviews. Maybe your `autoPinEdge` method does that for you? Seems unlikely but I guess it's possible…

Anyway, by making this a designated initializer, you can also make `inputField` a `let` instead of a `var`:

```
public let inputField: UITextField

init(withHeader header:String) {
    inputField = UITextField.init(forAutoLayout: ())

    super.init(frame:CGRect.zero)

    let headerLbl = UILabel.init(forAutoLayout: ())
    headerLbl.textColor = UIColor.red
    headerLbl.text = header

    addSubview(inputField)
    addSubview(headerLbl)

    headerLbl.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .top, of: self)
    headerLbl.autoPinEdge(.leading, to: .leading, of: self)

    inputField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    inputField.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: headerLbl)
    inputField.autoPinEdge(.leading, to: .leading, of: self)
    inputField.autoPinEdge(.right, to: .right, of: self)
    inputField.autoPinEdge(.bottom, to: .bottom, of: self, withOffset: -5)
}
```

Next, let's look at your override of `init(frame:)`:

> ```
> override init(frame: CGRect) {
>     super.init(frame: frame)
> }
> ```

This doesn't compile because, as a designated initializer, it's required to initialize your stored properties before calling `super.init`. But do you even want this initializer? It doesn't set up the label and the text field. Since it's not `required` by a superclass, you can just delete this initializer entirely.

Finally, here's your `NSCodable` initializer:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

You have to have this because `UIView` says it's `required`. This implementation was generated by a compiler fix-it. If you don't intend to load a `TextInputView` from a storyboard xib, this initializer is fine the way it is.

Comment: Well 1 you did explain it in great detail to me and now 2 your solution worked. I just didnt understand why I was telling me to set my parameters to optionals to make this work. That didnt make any sense to me. 

My other issue was that I thought I didnt have to call super.init(frame)... on the UIView I was creating since I was using auto layout to display my views programatticaly. this is my first swift project iv been doing objective c all this time. So I really thought I was doing too much for a simple custom initializer but now I know why it was happening